# Schrödinger equation with nonstandard boundary conditions

Tags: hyperbolic-pde, schrodinger-operators

Consider the partial differential equation
$$\psi_t(t,x)=i\kappa \psi_{xx}(t,x) ~\mbox{for}~ 0<(t,x)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$$
with boundary conditions
$$\psi(0,x)=0 ~\mbox{for}~ x>0,$$
$$\psi(t,0)=\psi_0(t) ~\mbox{for}~ t\ge0.$$

Are these equation uniquely solvable whenever $\psi_0$ is sufficiently smooth?

Can one give an explicit expression for the linear operator mapping $\psi_0$ to the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation under consideration is uniquely solvable in $H^s(\mathbb{R}^+)$, as soon as $\psi_0\in H^{(2s+1)/4}(\mathbb{R}^+)$, and there is a fairly explicit expression for the propagator. You can find these results, for example, in

J. L. Bona, S. Sun, B. Zhang,
Nonhomogeneous boundary-value problems for one-dimensional nonlinear Schrödinger equations, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.matpur.2017.11.001,

where also the nonlinear problem is investigated.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: The precise result is in Proposition 3.3. Do you know if the reasult easly extend to the 3-dimensional case of a Schrödinger equation in a halfspace, with boundary conditions given for $t\ge0$ on the bounding hyperplane?